# Hiding ag grid column conditionally in angular 13

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I wanted to hid one of the ag-grid column conditionally. this is my ag grid column definition i wanted to hide  'automaticStart' columns conditionally. i tired below options, but unable to hide. Could you please help me .

```
private gridApi!: GridApi<DataProcessing>;
public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'automaticStart',
      headerName: 'Automatic Start',
      width: 70,
      sortable: false,
      cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: {
        checkbox: true,
        updateAutomaticBatch: this.updateAutomaticBatch.bind(this),
      },
     
    }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadBatchFiles();
  }

 loadBatchFiles() {
    this.batchProcessing
      .getBatchProcessingFiles()
      .subscribe((data: DataProcessingView) => {
        this.batchFiles = data.storedFileViewDtoList;
        if (data.signOffEnabled) {
          //here trying to hide automaticStart
          const col = this.gridApi.getColumnDef('automaticStart')?.hide;
          const colDef = this.gridApi.getColumnDefs();
          if (colDef) {
            this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(colDef);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Never worked with this framework, but `this.gridApi.getColumnDef('automaticStart')?.hide` just reads the value of hide. You should try setting it to true

Comment: Yes tried with  this.gridApi.getColumnDef('automaticStart')?.hide == true  but no luck.

Comment: `==` is for comparision. use `=` for assigning the value. Also according to the docs (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-display-hide), there is also an `initialHide` that might be bettter suited.

Comment: No i tried both options but is not working 
const col = this.gridApi.getColumnDef('automaticStart');
          if(col){
            col.initialHide = true
            col.hide = true
          }

Comment: can u expain with proper code in stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setGridOption` method on the `gridApi` to set your column definitions dynamically.

```
this.gridApi.setGridOption("columnDefs", newColumnDefs);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ag-grid-packages-forked-wmszd7?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3q0006356kadeeikq4%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3p0002356k3l5fht9p%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3p0003356kmykeup5i%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3q0005356kt84e5qli%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrrvkh3p0002356k3l5fht9p%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3p0001356kdhgxp86o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrs07oa10002356isir8kclw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp.component.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3p0002356k3l5fht9p%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrs07oa10002356isir8kclw%2522%257D%252C%2522clrrvkh3q0005356kt84e5qli%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3p0004356krcx9hphf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3q0005356kt84e5qli%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3p0004356krcx9hphf%2522%257D%252C%2522clrrvkh3p0003356kmykeup5i%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrrvkh3p0003356kmykeup5i%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) is a working example.

You can find more details on updating column definitions [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-updating-definitions/).